# How to sort db items by descending order in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want sort the db items in descending order by `created_at` column in rails but I couldn't figured it out how?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to do order on all elements

```
   User.order('created_at DESC')
```

(OR)

```
   User.order(created_at: :desc)
```

If you want to have some condition

```
   User.where('your condition here').order(created_at: :desc)
```

(OR)

```
  User.order(created_at: :desc).where('your condition here')
```

Note: Replace User with your model name

Comment: Shouldn't need the `all` and you can use symbols for this order. Newer versions of Rails throw a warning or error about using raw sql for the order. So if you needed the sql ordering because of more complex joins for example you'd have to wrap in `Arel.sql[]` but since it's just on the model, you could just do `User.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: I kept 'all' just to for reference, if they want to use any where condition, they can use like that and thanks for the comment I will update my answer.